# Sparse matrix hstack getting error regarding subscriptability

Tags: python, scipy

Would someone please explain why this does not work?

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix, hstack
row = np.array([0,3,1,0])
col = np.array([0,3,1,2])
data = np.array([4,5,7,9])

temp = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)))
temp_stack = coo_matrix([0, 11,22,33], ([0, 1,2,3], [0, 0,0,0]))
temp_res = hstack(temp, temp_stack)
```

I get an error that `coo_matrix` is not subscriptable, but I don't understand why, it appears that I am concatenating matrices of compatible dimension.

Answer (score 1):

First note that the first argument of [`hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html) is expected to be a tuple containing the arrays to be stacked, so you should call it with `hstack((temp, temp_stack))`.

Next, `temp` has shape `(4, 4)` and `temp_stack` has shape `(1, 4)`.  These shapes can not be `hstack`ed.  What shape do expect the result to be?  If you are trying to create a result that has shape `(5, 4)`, use [`vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.vstack.html):

```
In [28]: result = vstack((temp, temp_stack))

In [29]: result.A
Out[29]: 
array([[ 4,  0,  9,  0],
       [ 0,  7,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  5],
       [ 0, 11, 22, 33]], dtype=int64)
```

If you meant for `temp_stack` to have shape `(4, 1)`, then fix how it is created by adding an extra level of parentheses in the call of `coo_matrix`:

```
In [38]: temp_stack = coo_matrix(([0, 11, 22, 33], ([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0])))

In [39]: temp_stack.shape
Out[39]: (4, 1)

In [40]: result = hstack((temp, temp_stack))

In [41]: result.A
Out[41]: 
array([[ 4,  0,  9,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  7,  0,  0, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 22],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  5, 33]], dtype=int64)
```

---

By the way, I think it is a SciPy bug that this call

```
temp_stack = coo_matrix([0, 11,22,33], ([0, 1,2,3], [0, 0,0,0]))
```

does not raise an error.  That call is equivalent to

```
temp_stack = coo_matrix(arg1=[0, 11,22,33], shape=([0, 1,2,3], [0, 0,0,0]))
```

and that `shape` value is clearly not valid.  That call to `coo_matrix` should raise a `ValueError`.  I created an issue for this on the SciPy github site: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9919

Comment: It appears that if the first argument (to `coo_matrix`) is not a tuple, it's assumed to be a matrix (sparse or dense), and it ignores all following arguments (keyword or not).  I suspect that pattern of argument handling is true for all the sparse formats, and has been that way since the start.